# Webpack and modernizr causes TypeError: document is undefined error

Tags: modernizr, webpack

I am using webpack to bundle up my javascript files.

My Webpack config (which is passed to webpack using gulp) looks like this:

```
    var webpackConfig = {
        context: __dirname,
        entry: {
            "app": "./js/app.js"
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, ".."),
            filename: "/js/[name].js",
            chunkFilename: "/js/[id].js"
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
                new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
            )
        ],
        resolve: {
            modulesDirectories: ['js', 'bower_components', 'node_modules']
        }
    };
```

My `app.js` is a simple require:

```
require('modernizr/modernizr.js');
```

Webpack builds the file without any problems and the generated file contains modernizr.

The problem is that when I include the file on a page and test it, modernizr errors out:

```
TypeError: document is undefined

docElement = document.documentElement,
```

The bundled file from webpack looks like this:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    __webpack_require__(1);

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    /*!
     * Modernizr v2.8.3
     * www.modernizr.com
     *
     * Copyright (c) Faruk Ates, Paul Irish, Alex Sexton
     * Available under the BSD and MIT licenses: www.modernizr.com/license/
     */

    /*
     * Modernizr tests which native CSS3 and HTML5 features are available in
     * the current UA and makes the results available to you in two ways:
     * as properties on a global Modernizr object, and as classes on the
     * <html> element. This information allows you to progressively enhance
     * your pages with a granular level of control over the experience.
     *
     * Modernizr has an optional (not included) conditional resource loader
     * called Modernizr.load(), based on Yepnope.js (yepnopejs.com).
     * To get a build that includes Modernizr.load(), as well as choosing
     * which tests to include, go to www.modernizr.com/download/
     *
     * Authors        Faruk Ates, Paul Irish, Alex Sexton
     * Contributors   Ryan Seddon, Ben Alman
     */

    window.Modernizr = (function( window, document, undefined ) {

        var version = '2.8.3',

        Modernizr = {},

        /*>>cssclasses*/
        // option for enabling the HTML classes to be added
        enableClasses = true,
        /*>>cssclasses*/

        docElement = document.documentElement,

        /** rest of modernizr code here **/

        return Modernizr;

    })(this, this.document);


/***/ }
/******/ ])
```

What's causing this problem?

Comment: I've got the same problem with browserify + debowerify. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Ilkka See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by Modernizr passing `this.document` to the closure it creates. Unfortunately, webpack wraps all that in yet another closure of its own, causing `this.document` to return `null`.

The problem can be resolved by setting `this` using the [imports loader](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader) when requiring:

```
require('imports?this=>window!modernizr/modernizr.js');
```

Comment: In my project modernizr is being required quite a lot, so don't want to change everywhere. Can I add something in a loader so that every required file has ```this=window``` by default?

Answer (score 3):

On Webpack 2, I think I got it working by using `{test: /modernizr/, loader: 'imports-loader?this=>window!exports-loader?window.Modernizr'}`, in my `module.rules`.

See this Webpack bug filed here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/512#issuecomment-288143187

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but was not requiring Modernizr directly. I required a library that had Modernizr packaged in it. The earlier solution does not work in that scenario. I eventually ended up using the [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader):

```
require('script!package/vendor-bundle.js);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Webpack config file added this :

```
module: {
    ...
    loaders: [
        ...
        { test: /[\\\/]modernizr dependecie path[\\\/]modernizr\.js$/,
            loader: "imports?this=>window!exports?window.Modernizr" }
        ...
    ]
}
```

for that you'll need to install the `imports-loader` and `exports-loader` .