# Import/compile HTML theme's JS libraries in webpack (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

The HTML theme has one  tag per JS file in the footer, like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.8/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js" ></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/5.0.0/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js'></script>
```

but in my Laravel installation, I wanted to have them all bundled into a single file, so I have downloaded each file and updated app.js like this:

```
import '../assets/js/jquery.min.js';
import '../assets/libraries/gsap.min.js';
import '../assets/libraries/ScrollTrigger.min.js';
import '../assets/libraries/ScrollToPlugin.min.js';
import '../assets/libraries/Draggable.min.js';
import '../assets/libraries/EasePack.min.js';
import '../assets/libraries/ScrollMagic.min.js';
import '../assets/libraries/animation.gsap.min.js';
import '../assets/libraries/three.min.js';
import '../assets/libraries/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js';
```

But webpack throws the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/libraries/animation.gsap.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'TimelineMax' in 'path\to\file'

ERROR in ./resources/assets/libraries/animation.gsap.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'TweenMax' in 'path\to\file'

webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

I know that if any of the files was missing jQuery then we could declare it like this:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Then how can I get TimelineMax and TweenMax from the local gsap file, so that the animation.gsap file can find them?

Comment: I would personally not recommend to bundle all of those into a single file, it is better to have them on separate files so they load (not download) faster and because it is a CDN, it will be cached and be local and you will not waste a si gle byte of bandwith for those files

Comment: @matiaslauriti I understand but I worry that in some countries the CDN might get blocked or load too slowly due to the distance from the closest servers.

Comment: I believe that the issue is probably that webpack wraps every separate import into its own container, like the accepted solution explains here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229323/webpack-and-modernizr-causes-typeerror-document-is-undefined-error

Webpack says that we can always put the libraries into their own vendors.js file, either way I'd like to understand how we can compile these files in a manner that their functions can still talk to each other

Comment: I see... I have never done that, because I did not have the need to, but could you tell us which Laravel version you have? I am assuming you are using webpack 100% and you are nto confusing webpack (Laravel Mix) with Vite, right?

Comment: Laravel 10 with Mix. There is no confusion.